# How to change icon in Bootstrap collapse for multiple requirments

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have used Bootstrap collapse for three different div for different requirments.

**First Collapse div :** I need to change "glypicon-left and bottom icon"  of "showing text and hide".

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <span class="badge">
        <span>0</span>
    </span>
    <span> Function</span>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" class="fb_down_arrow">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<ul class="fb_list_option collapse in" id="collapse1">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c5" name="cc">
        <label for="c5"><span></span>Corporate Real Estate</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Second Collapse div :** I need to change "glypicon-plus and minus" icon of "showing text and hide".

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c92" name="cc">
    <label for="c92"><span></span>Construction (###)</label>
    <a href="" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fb_plus_one" class="" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus fb_list_plus_arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul id="fb_plus_one" class="collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="c01" name="cc">
            <label for="c01"><span></span>Child 1</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**Third Collapse div :** I need to change "glypicon-left and bottom icon" and also change Text of "show more" , "less more" of showing text and hide.

```
<a href="#demo1" class="doc_right_title collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">See more detail <span class="glyphicon KB_glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></span></a>
<div class="row collapse in" id="demo1" aria-expanded="true">

</div>
```

Script:
I am using below script archiving first collapse  div requirement.kindly advise how to to archive second & third collapse.

```
// Collapse Start 
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-triangle-left")
        .removeClass("glyphicon-triangle-left")
        .addClass("glyphicon-triangle-bottom");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-triangle-bottom")
        .removeClass("glyphicon-triangle-bottom")
        .addClass("glyphicon-triangle-left");
});
// Collapse End
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
e.stopImmediatePropagation()
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-triangle-left").first().removeClass("glyphicon-triangle-left").addClass("glyphicon-triangle-bottom");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
e.stopImmediatePropagation()
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-triangle-bottom").first().removeClass("glyphicon-triangle-bottom").addClass("glyphicon-triangle-left");
});
```